# объясните пожалуйста доступно

Tags: javascript

объясните пожалуйста доступно(не одним словом),почему у объекта x все 3 значения равны 3 а не 1 2 3 как я думаю .в следующем коде

```
function foo(){       
   var a =[ ];                        
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; I++)                                          
     a.push(function(){ print(i) } );                                          
   return a;
}  

var x=foo();
```

Comment: Про замыкание знаете?

Comment: замыкание это область видимости?

Comment: выразить ничего не хотел,это учебный материал

Comment: Что бы получилось то что хочешь, просто замени  `for(var` ' var  'на 'let'

Comment: я хочу понять откуда берется именно 3 3 3 x[0] x[1] x[2]

Comment: Потому что переменная/ссылка `i` не уникальная для каждого вызова, там адрес один и тот же, по этому будет доступно последнее установленное значение, полученное после выполнения цикла, всех его итераций. Нужно замыкание, что бы образовать специальную область видимости где будет хранится уникальное значение

Comment: спасибо.немогу оценить.репутации не хватает.)

Comment: Не обязательно замыкание, можно вместо `var i = 0` писать `let i = 0`

Comment: @Илья Зеленько,а что let i = 0 уже не замыкание?

Comment: В коде вопроса уже есть замыкание. let создает для каждой итерации свою локальную переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Что вы хотели в этом алгоритме выразить? В стек (массив по принципу стека) помещается три функции, с индексами `{0, 1, 2}` внутри которой находится вызов функции для печати, в которую передается одно и тоже значение! Внутри массива, можно вызвать нужный элемент, то есть функцию синтаксиса `x[0]()`; Если необходимо передать уникальные значения, то требуется воспользоваться замыканиями. К примеру:

```js
function foo() {
    var a = [];
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
        a.push((function(i){ return function() {
            console.log(i); 
        } })(i)); 
    return a;
} 
var x=foo();
x[0]();
x[1]();
x[2]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно для каждой функции свой i, то можно вместо `var i = 0;` писать `let i = 0;`

```js
function foo(){       
   var a =[ ];                        
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)                                          
     a.push(function(){ return i } );                                          
   return a;
}  

var x=foo();

for (el of x) 
  console.log(el())
```

Вот детально объяснение проблемы и 3 варианта решения(варианта с let там нет, но так тоже можно): https://learn.javascript.ru/task/make-army