# Кто может объяснить, почему при клике на item, цикл уже пройден?

Tags: javascript

При клике на какой либо из item'ов цикл уже пройден, то есть i == 4. Кто может на пальцах объяснить.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');


for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

```css
.items {
    display: flex;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.active {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Типичный вопрос на всех собеседованиях. Погуглите про замыкание

Comment: при добавлении слушателя событий никакое событие не происходит, но если передать значение обработчику события то тогда он будет выводить его когда событие произойдет. То есть цикл прокручивается, а переменная тоже прокручивается вместе с циклом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В функцию обработчика события клика вы передаете одну и ту же переменную, не ее значение! А так как вы нажимаете на элемент после цикла, то выводится ее конечное значение(4). Самый простой способ решить проблему - в цикле заменить var на let, при этом решении для каждой итерации(шаг цикла) будет создана своя локальная переменная i.

[Вчера отвечал на этот вопрос.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873665/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE/873689#873689)

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');


for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

```css
.items {
    display: flex;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.active {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Есть более старое решение: тут же вызвать ф-ю обертку с локальной переменной которая возвращает ф-ю которая уже будет участвовать в обработке события.

```js
items[i].addEventListener('click', 
  (function (localI) {
      return function (event) { alert(localI) };
  }(i))
);
```